# BigNumber lib for Node.js gives wrong RSA decryption

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to learn some cryptography, so I decided to take on the challenge given in the YouTube video [How the RSA algorithm works, including how to select d, e, n, p, q, and φ (phi)](https://youtu.be/Z8M2BTscoD4) using Node.js.

The challenge is thus:

Encrypt the secret using `m^e mod n = c`, and then decrypt it using `c^d mod n = m`, and then the following data is given:

```
// Secret Message:
const m = 42;

// Prime Numbers:
const p = 61, q = 53;

// Other numbers:
const e = 17, n = 3233, d = 2753;
```

Sadly I quickly discovered that `Math.pow(c, d)` yields `Infinity`, so I went `$ npm install big-number --save` and did `BigNumber(c).pow(d)` instead. This yielded an actual number, but the final result after the modulus operation is still wrong. I get the number 24 when it should be 42, and I just can't for the life of me understand why (though knowing myself it's probably due to something really dumb).

Here are the rather naïve functions I made to solve the problem:

```
function encryptRSA(m, e, n) {
    // return Math.pow(m, e) % n; // yields 1278 and not 2557
    return BigNumber(m).pow(e).mod(n);
}
```

...and...

```
function decryptRSA(c, d, n) {
    // return Math.pow(c, d) % n; // yileded 'Infinity' so dl'd BigNumber
    return BigNumber(c).pow(d).mod(n);
}
```

Question is, why does the last function return 24 and not 42? And how can I fix it?

---

So it turns out it the solution was really dumb as expected. The number is stored backwards in the object BigNumber.number. Though when printed in a string, it is shown correctly. I still don't know why that is, though, so an answer to that would still be pretty interesting.

I would also be extremely grateful for an answer to why the regular modulus operations yields the wrong answer, especially in the first function, though I guess it has to do with physical number length vs memory restrictions...

Comment: you want `modPow` https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/blob/1a0d6fbfe1f747f9ff5eff9d9f6f71185d6cd63c/BigInteger.js#L612

Comment: No I don't. The solution was dumb as expected. The array is reverted, but when set with a string, it shows the correct answer. :p :p :p Not sure why it's turned on its head in array form, though.

Comment: But seriously, for rsa you want a modPow function. Doing pow followed by a mod is extremely inefficient and would likely fail for real world RSA numbers, especially the decrypt operation.

Comment: Since you put it that way! Thanks, I will! :) Just trying to learn now, so knowing how and why is really important to me. Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: JavaScript internally uses floating point ops. If the numbers get big you should not be surprised if the answer is incorrect because there is only a limited amount of precision.